# Sass variable change to css variable?

Tags: css, webpack, sass

How i can do this?

**// style.scss**

```
$primary-color: #dc4545;

div{
    background : $primary-color;
}
```

**Try to do this:**

```
div{
    background : var(--primary-color)
}
```

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Interesting question, here's a tutorial which may help: https://codepen.io/jakealbaugh/post/css4-variables-and-sass

Answer (score 6):

You can define global variables on the `:root`:

```
:root {
  --primary-color: #dc4545; 
}

div {
  background: var(--primary-color); 
}
```

Edit: Or were you trying to mix and match?

```
$primary-color: #dc4545;

:root {
  --primary-color: #{$primary-color}; 
}

div {
  background: var(--primary-color); 
}
```

Comment: i know how much variable are used in this project . But is not possible to change one by one because those variable are used more then one file so is that any other way to convert  .

Comment: Unfortunately not the SASS variables exists pre-compiled only so for CSS to recognize the variable you'll need to convert it to be defined on CSS first.

Answer (score -1):

First of all :root and html selector basically same thing but :root with higher specificity than html selector

```css
html {
  
}

/*****exactly :root and html selector are same but with higher specifity(:root)*****/
:root {
  --color-primary-light: #FF3366;
  --color-primary-dark: #BA265D;
  --bakcground-color: #fff;
  --default-font-size: 16px;
  --color: blue;
  }
  
  /****************How to implement***************/
  .root-selector {
    background-color: var(--background-color);
    font-size: var(--default-font-size);
    color: var(--color);
  }
```

```html
<div class="root-selector">
  Thank you buddy
</div>
```

Comment: *:root with higher specificity* --> what do you mean by this? root will select nothing, so there no specificity here